# how to return 0 for count of match that doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I'm using an aggregation where I match if a value is in an array then group those like values:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {
       $match: {"city":{ $in: ["New York", "Denver"]}}
    },{
       $group: {_id: "$city", total : {$sum:1}}
    }
])

{_id:"New York", total:5}
{_id:"Denver", total:2}
```

this works in the case city is in the values but I would like to return total:0 in the case city isn't in the set. ie:

```
["New York", "Denver", "Orlando"]


{_id:"New York", total:5}
{_id:"Denver", total:2}
{_id:"Orlando", total:0}
```

Is this possible or should I just check the results in my code and append the 0 value results to the results?

Comment: Have you tried omitting the $match stage?

Comment: I need the match stage but even if that was gone it wouldn't solve the issue at hand. I would just return a bunch of other cities none of which would ever have total:0 since those don't exist in the collection.